# How should accuracy for a multiclass problem be calculated?

Tags: machine-learning, accuracy, model-evaluation

How should accuracy for a multiclass problem be calculated?

a) Overall accuracy: All_True_Positives/All_classes

b) Average of all the accuracies from each class. (Sum each accuracy and divide by the number of classes).

Thank you

Comment: One might suppose how it *should* be calculated would depend on how much each kind of error costs you.  That suggests your question does not have a universal answer--and if one is offered, you ought to examine it very critically to make sure it really makes sense for your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [Confusion Matrix](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html), which explains the **precision** and **recall** of the model.  These two numbers tell you how many classifications your model got correct (precision), and how many classes it should have classified but didnt (recall).

Depending on the business use-case of your model, you want to optimize for one or the other.

Comment: I can calculate Accuracy from the confusion matrix in both ways. That is why I am asking which one is the correct way to do it. Scikit uses option "a", meanwhile a github library uses option "b".

Comment: Im not sure which library you're referring to, but I would stick with the Scikit implementation.

Comment: And in this paper: "A systematic analysis of performance measures for classification tasks" in page 430, table 3; it seems that it agrees with the github library: https://github.com/pandas-ml/pandas-ml. (which is option b).